# Catch Command flags variable with codegangsta/cli

Tags: go, command-line-interface, undefined

I try to write my first CLI App in Go.

I use codegangsta/cli for the structure.

My problem :

I have some commands :

```
Add  --name 

Show --all

Delete  --force
```

From the file **/commands/add.go** I can't get the variable `StackName` from **/commands.go** set like this :

```
package main
var StackName string
var Commands = []cli.Command{
{
    Name:   "add",
    Usage:  "",
    Action: command.CmdAdd,

    Flags:  []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name: "name, n",
            Value: "default",
            Usage: "Stack name",
            Destination: &StackName,
        },
```

And in my add.go file, I try to get $stackName but I don't find how to do this :

```
package command

func CmdAdd(c *cli.Context) {
    fmt.PrintF(StackName)
}
```

I got this : `command/add.go:25: undefined: StackName`.

Thanks to help to find where I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know much of "codegangsta/cli" and the way it works but you declare variable in the "package main" and want to access it in the "package command".

Answer (score 0):

What does your file hierarchy look like? Because you may need to import the commands.go file `import "github.com/YourGithubName/YourDirectory/commands"`. I say this because you are trying to call the variable in the command package when it is declared in the main package.

Comment: Hi Ethan, Here is my code https://github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker 
I try to get a variable from 'commands.go' in the commands/add.go file but I doesn't work because they dont use the same package 'main'.

Comment: Within the add.go file, since you are trying to use a variable from another package simply add import "github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker" to the add.go file. Or are you trying to do it the other way around?

Comment: I have try this solution but I got this error in the go build process : ` import "github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker" is a program, not an importable package` I just want to use the global variable `StackName` from commands.go but don't find how..

Comment: yes and since StackName is within the main package of github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker you must import it. add a /main to the end of the import since that is the package name correct?

Comment: It not seem to be the correct thing to do :
cannot find package "github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker/main"

cannot find package "github.com/valentin2105/kubeStacker/main.go"

(I have use https://github.com/tcnksm/gcli.git to create the skeletton). 
Thanks
:)

Comment: put the commands.go file under package kubeStacker then include the import path to the project.